# Select the last 3 entry of a model database

Tags: django, sqlite

Hi i have simple question

How can i select only the last 3 entry of a table from a database table ?

I want to display the 3 last news on a news wall but for now i just select all the table and loop only 3 time through the resulting array.

I want to be able to get only the 3 latest news directly with the query (if it's even possible)

Views.py

```
def accueil(request):
news=News.objects.order_by('-date')
return render(request,'dashboard/dashboard.html',{'last_news':news})
```

Template:

```
{% for news in last_news %}
            {% if forloop.counter < 4 %}
                <div class="news">
                    <h3>{{ news.title }}</h3>
                    <p>{{ news.content|truncatewords_html:80 }}</p>
                    <p><a href="{% url "dashboard.views.lireNews" news.id %}">Lire la suite</a></p>
                </div>
         {% endif %}
    {% empty %}
        <p>Aucun news.</p>

    {% endfor %}
     </div>
```

Comment: is my answer what you were looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply limit your queryset, as described in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets).

```
news=News.objects.order_by('-date')[:3]
```